# Storyboard displaying different results on device after adding setNavigationBarHidden

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have recently added the code below to remove the navigation bar on ONLY the first control. This has worked but now the storyboard displays a different result on my iphone device than it does on the computer. This was not the case before. You can see what I mean from the links(My reputation is not big enough to post images:

[Storyboard Representation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nda2d8dk6xphnvb/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-16%20at%2022.09.25.png)

[iPhone Representation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yvtlmx0dbqwxdmf/IMG_2428.PNG)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

I am fairly new with xcode. Is this a common issue with storyboard design? Is there a way to rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storyboard actually has nothing to do with the "actual" result you are going to see on your device. The thing is, it's just a graphical representation of the UI and you can change that at any moment in code, just like you did. So don't worry, it's perfectly normal. Good luck!